# boost::container::flat_multimap crash on OSX/AppleClang in Release mode

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I seem to have an issue with boost::container::flat_multimap (Boost 1.66.0) on MacOS/AppleClang in **Release** mode (-O3). I tested in Ubuntu 17.10/GCC7.2 and Oracle Linux/GCC7.2.1 and the issues do not appear there.

Below is a minimum reproducible example.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>

using multimap = boost::container::flat_multimap<int *, int>;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    multimap map;
    std::vector<std::pair<int *, int>> key_value_pairs;

    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
        int * new_int = new int;
        *new_int = k;
        map.emplace(new_int, k);
        key_value_pairs.emplace_back(new_int, k);
    }

    for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();) {
        if (it->first == key_value_pairs[0].first) {
            it = map.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }

    // Should only be one map element left (key_value_pairs[1])
    auto it = map.find(key_value_pairs[1].first);
    if (it == map.end()) {
        throw std::logic_error("Could not find key");
    }

    std::cout  << "Success!" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Clang version

```
hoc$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

In this example, we generate 2 int pointers and insert them as the key into the boost::container::flat_multimap. Then we traverse the map and erase one of the entries by identifying the key. Subsequently we try to find the non-erased element by key, but sometimes it is not found (the std::logic_error at line 31 is triggered sometimes).

Is there a bug in my code? Or the container?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything actually /wrong/ with the code.

There is quite a bit of code smell - does the "equivalent" program here show the same problem?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9e1c0319762029e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using multimap = boost::container::flat_multimap<int *, int>;

int main() {
    int ks[] = { 0, 1 }; // allocation pool outlives map and key_value_pairs

    multimap map;
    for (int &k : ks)
        map.emplace(&k, k);

    std::vector<multimap::value_type> const key_value_pairs(map.begin(), map.end());

    map.erase(key_value_pairs[0].first);

    assert(map.size() == 1);
    assert(map.begin()->first == key_value_pairs[1].first);

    assert(map.count(&ks[0]) == 0);
    assert(map.count(&ks[1]) == 1);
}
```

Comment: Yes this appears to run fine. But you are using a different overload of erase than the one I am using in my example.

When I replace your map.erase with the for loop in my example, the first assert triggers.

Comment: Ah. Lightbulb. That's it. I forgot it's not a tree-based map. Updating the answer.

Comment: I dont believe your explanation is correct.

In all the other map types (including std::map and std::multimap), the iterator-erase overloads return an iterator to the element after the erase.

There would be little reason to return that iterator in boost::container::flat_multimap if it is always invalidated.

Using the key-erase overload is not an option in our application.

Comment: Are you saying the documentation is a lie? It's pretty clear, and obviously makes sense, because otherwise there would be no difference between `std::map` and `flat_map`. Of course, you could need this overload, but in that case you either need to use a container with iterator stability **or** order the `erase` calls such that the iterator invalidation suits your needs.

Comment: There's no reason why the erase cant return a valid iterator (after it has invalidated all the existing iterators) just because it is backed by a vector.

In fact, the docs say it does this:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html#idp47710672-bb

Comment: Not only that but it appears to do so correctly for all other optimization modes on AppleClang and does so for GCC on all optimization modes.

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah. You are making sense too. You're right. Then my lightbulb went off again. There must be a bug in the implementation of either `flat_map`, `libc++` or the compiler is generating invalid code. Mmm. I don't have a mac so I won't be able to reproduce things for now. (Rolled back the answer)